# glError 1282 in the Nexus S but not in the Nexus One

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am creating a live wallpaper using openGL ES 2.0.
The app works great in my nexus one but it doesn't not show anything in a Nexus S.

Things I have tested so far:

- I have already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781369/opengl-es-problem-on-nexus-s). My texture is 128x128 so I guess this isn't the issue.
- I have used the `checkGlError` method in my code and I found that it passes the `onSurfaceCreated` and `onSurfaceChanged` without issues. The method throws an exception if I call it in the first line of the `onDrawFrame()` method.

The `checkGlError` code is the following:

```
private void checkGlError(String op) {
    int error;
    while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        Log.e(TAG, op + ": glError " + error);
        throw new RuntimeException(op + ": glError " + error);
    }
}
```

I notice that the error occurs in both devices, but it looks critical in the nexus S while it draws fine in the nexus one. My guess is that the shader is not compiled correctly and there is an issue there.

Do you know other incompatibilities between the nexus S and the nexus one?
Is there a way of debugging shader's code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end my issue was related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781369/opengl-es-problem-on-nexus-s).

When reading from resources Android resized my texture. I solved it reading the texture from the raw folder:

```
public void loadBitmap(int resourceId) {

        textureId = resourceId;

        /* Get the texture */
        InputStream is = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(textureId);
        Bitmap bitmap;

        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Ignore.
            }
        }

        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();

        Buffer data = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * 4);
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(data);
        data.position(0);

        // Bind the texture object
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures.get(0));
        ...
        // OpenGL stuff
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know other incompatibilities between the nexus S and the nexus one?

Not what I'm aware of, although there surely are possibilities where the OpenGL ES driver differs from phone to phone.

> Is there a way of debugging shader's code?

I haven't experimented with shaders myself, but however, I can check regular translations, rotations, etc, with debugging *on* on my `GLSurfaceView`.

Try set this on your `GLSurfaceView` and check if you are able to see changes in LogCat:

```
mGLSurfaceView.setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR 
    | GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS);
```