# GLES20 Texture Not Working on Some Devices

Tags: android, opengl-es, texture-mapping, texture2d, nexus-s

I have tried to add a fairly simple extension on top of [Android's example OpenGL 2.0 project](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html) in order to add texturing to basic shapes. This **seems** pretty straightforward, but on certain devices (Samsung Nexus S, LG Optimus 3D, Samsung Galaxy S) the texture just does not render.

*This is actually a problem that I am having on a much larger project, but I was able to reproduce the issue with the simple project below in the hope that someone here has an idea of where my code presents issues, or how to specifically architect GL textures for these devices (maybe there are issues with the devices).*

To give an idea of how this object is used: In the GLSurfaceView.Renderer's `onSurfaceCreated` method I am instantiating a `Square()` object and in the `onDrawFrame` method I am calling Square's `draw()` method. However, all of the relevant code to dealing with textures should appear in this Square class which is almost exactly identical to Google's own example.

Many thanks in advance to anyone who takes a crack at this.

```
class Square {

private final String vertexShaderCode =
    // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
    // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +

    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
    "attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate;" +

    "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +

    "void main() {" +
    // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
    "  gl_Position = vPosition * uMVPMatrix;" +
    "  v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;" +
    "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
    "precision mediump float;" +

    "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;" +

    "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +

    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate);" +
    "}";

private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private final FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
private final ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
private final int mProgram;
private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
static float squareCoords[] = { -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
                                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
                                 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
                                 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right

final float[] previewTextureCoordinateData =
    {
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f
    };

private int textureDataHandle;
private int textureUniformHandle;
private int textureCoordinateHandle;

private final short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices

private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

// Set color with red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
float color[] = { 0.2f, 0.709803922f, 0.898039216f, 1.0f };

private int loadTexture(final Context context, final int resourceId)
{
    final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

    if (textureHandle[0] != 0)
    {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;   // No pre-scaling

        // Read in the resource
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, options);

        // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
        bitmap.recycle();
    }

    if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
    }

    return textureHandle[0];
}

public Square(Context context) {
    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
    // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            squareCoords.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
    // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
            drawOrder.length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);


    ByteBuffer texCoordinates = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(previewTextureCoordinateData.length * 4);
    texCoordinates.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = texCoordinates.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(previewTextureCoordinateData);
    textureBuffer.position(0);

    // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
    int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                                               vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                                                 fragmentShaderCode);

    textureDataHandle = loadTexture(context, R.drawable.color_texture);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables
}

public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                 GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                 vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

    textureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_TexCoordinate");
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordinateHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 
            0, textureBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordinateHandle);

    textureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "u_Texture");
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureDataHandle);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(textureUniformHandle, 0);      

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    // Draw the square
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
                          GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll guess that this is a Power-of-two problem.

By default, the `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP` setting of `glTexParameter` is set to `GL_REPEAT`, and textures that use `GL_REPEAT` **must** be power-of-two sized:

> Similarly, if the width or height of a texture image are not powers of two and either the 
>               GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER is set to one of the functions that requires mipmaps
>               **or the GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S or GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T is not
>               set to GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE**, then the texture image unit will return
>               (R, G, B, A) = (0, 0, 0, 1).

You may start with a power-of-two texture, but when you use a `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` to generate a bitmap, it helpfully(?) scales this based on the density of a device. So for example if you load a 512*512 source texture from `drawable` folder on a HDPI device, I believe it scales it by 1.5x, so you're left with something that is not Po2.

This gives you the result that your textures don't work on a ton of devices, because those devices are all of a density that causes you to generate illegal texture sizes.

The solution in this case would be to place your (power of 2) source texture into the resource folder `drawable-nodpi`, which will prevent any density-based scaling. Either that or use CLAMP_TO_EDGE, which doesn't care about Po2.

Comment: This does indeed solve the problem! Now I need to figure out how to apply this to an incoming camera feed image... which almost certainly will stray from being a Po2 on many phones. I will read more about the GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE and see how best to use textures that are nPo2 – any useful resources you know of?

Comment: You should be fine with NPO2 textures, as long as you don't need texcoord wrapping. I'd just set everything to CLAMP_TO_EDGE unless you specifically need the functionality.

Comment: You can check for GL_OES_texture_npot extension to check if non-power-of-two textures are supported. Please read more here http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_npot.txt

List of supported extensions for almost every possible Android devices can be found on GLBenchmark site, example: http://www.glbenchmark.com/phonedetails.jsp?benchmark=glpro25&D=Google+Nexus+One&testgroup=gl

Comment: The easiest move is to take the camera image and place it into a texture that *is* Po2, and retrieve it as a subtexture. But either way moving the camera to the gpu will be slow.